# Switching user in openssh using PAM

Tags: linux, openssh, pam

I'm trying to write a PAModule which will use compare the inserted username against a file.
If the username exists in the file, it will change the username to root (since the username does not really exist as a local account) and then will log in as root.

However, I've noticed that it's not possible (I guess that at least not by default) to change the username via OpenSSH.

Is there a way of enabling this option (modifying OpenSSH code is also a valid option, but surely not a preferred one.)

Comment: What's wroing with having the client connect as root in the first place?

Comment: @Keith the idea is to confirm authentication via an external module without the user to exist as a local account.

Comment: So you want any user to map to root?

Comment: @Keith yes, as long as the external module confirms it.